# format specifier for short integer

Tags: c++, c, debugging, format-specifiers

I don't use correctly the format specifiers in C. A few lines of code:

```
int main()
{
        char dest[]="stack";
        unsigned short val = 500;
        char c = 'a';

        char* final = (char*) malloc(strlen(dest) + 6);

        snprintf(final, strlen(dest)+6, "%c%c%hd%c%c%s", c, c, val, c, c, dest); 

        printf("%s\n", final);
        return 0;
}
```

What I want is to copy at

final [0] = a random char
   final [1] = a random char
   final [2] and final [3] = the short array
   final [4] = another char ....

My problem is that i want to copy the two bytes of the short int to 2 bytes of the final array.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm confused - the problem is that you are saying `strlen(dest)+6` which limits the length of the `final` string to 10 chars (plus a null terminator). If you say `strlen(dest)+8` then there will be enough space for the full string.

**Update**

Even though a short may only be 2 bytes in size, when it is printed as a string each character will take up a byte. So that means it can require up to 5 bytes of space to write a short to a string, if you are writing a number above 10000.

Now, if you write the short to a string as a hexadecimal number using the `%x` format specifier, it will take up no more than 2 bytes.

Comment: I want to add 4 bytes (4 characters) and 2 more for a short integer, ie 6 characters

Comment: @cateof: But your short integer could use up to 5 characters (bytes) when formatted as a string.  It's using 3 in this case (500).

Comment: @cateof You forgot the NULL character, and when you convert your short to a string it becomes "500", which is three characters long and takes up three bytes. I believe the max short is 32767, so you should leave five bytes of space to be sure it'll fit

Comment: It's unsigned, so the max is 65535.  But it's still five characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for 13 characters - not 11. Don't forget the terminating NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You lose one byte because you think the short variable takes 2 byte. But it takes three: one for each digit character ('5', '0', '0'). Also you need a `'\0'` terminator (+1 byte).

==> You need `strlen(dest) + 8`

Comment: a, ok. That is the problem. So i need to try it  again.

I want to create a char array that contains 
1st byte = a random char
2nd byte = a ramdom char
3rd and 4th byte = a short int
5th byte = a random char.

So how can I copy the short int to a byte array?

Comment: Best to clarify your question to reflect those updated requirements.

Answer (score 1):

`Unsigned short`s can take up to 5 characters, right?  (0 - 65535)

Seems like you'd need to allocate 5 characters for your `unsigned short` to cover all of the values.

Which would point to using this:

```
char* final = (char*) malloc(strlen(dest) + 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

When formatted the number (500) takes up three spaces, not one.  So your `snsprintf` should give the final length as `strlen(dest)+5+3`.  Then also fix your `malloc` call to adjust.  If you want to compute the `strlen` of the number, do that with a call like this `strlen(itoa(val))`.  Also, cant forget the NULL at the end of dest, but I think strlen takes this into account, but I'm not for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is you only allocated enough space for the strlen(dest) + 6 characters when in all reality it looks like you're going to have 8 extra characters... since you have 2 chars + 3 chars in your number + 2 chars after + dest (5 chars) = 13 char when you allocated 11 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use 8 instead of 6 on:

```
char* final = (char*) malloc(strlen(dest) + 6);
```

and

```
snprintf(final, strlen(dest)+6, "%c%c%hd%c%c%s", c, c, val, c, c, dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the primary misunderstanding is that a "2-byte" short can't be represented on-screen as 2 1-byte characters.

First, leave enough room:

```
char* final = (char*) malloc(strlen(dest) + 9);
```

The entire range of possible values for a 1-byte character are not printable. If you want to display this on screen and be readable, you'll have to encode the 2-byte short as 4 hex bytes, such as:

```
## as hex, 4 characters
snprintf(final, sizeof(final), "%c%c%4x%c%c%s", c, c, val, c, c, dest);
```

If you are writing this to a file, that's OK, and you might try the following:

```
## print raw bytes, upper byte, then lower byte.
snprintf(final, sizeof(final), "%c%c%c%c%c%c%s", c, c, ((val<<8)&0xFF), ((val>>8)&0xFF), c, c, dest);
```

But that won't make sense to a human looking at it, and is sensitive to endianness. I'd strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Another caveat - the raw bytes snprintf statement only works for an *unsigned* short int.